# Table component not rendered in Internet Explorer until some submit

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf, rendering, trinidad

I'm using JSF with trinidad to render a table. It works fine in all browsers except for IE 6/7/8.

After I click on a submit button which refresh the whole panel the table is being rendered.

Any idea in general what could cause this behavior?

Comment: How many columns/rows are in that table? IE6/7/8 has an extremely poor table renderer and chokes often when it exceeds a X amount of columns/rows wherein X is usually an insane amount such as 1000.

Comment: it's not the case , cause i have only one column..

Comment: How about rows? 1 column and 1000 rows still forms a problem in IE6/7/8.

Comment: Well, then I don't know. It's probably Trinidad which I am not familiar with. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update when i'll understand this issue..

Comment: Could you try add an on document load Javascript containing something like `document.body.className += ''`? It's a long-shot, but it might help.